# PHP Json library not inherited in subdirectories

Tags: php, json, .htaccess, hosting, cpanel

I'm trying to run a project on the server, When I put the file on the root (html_public) folder it works but once I move the file into a folder I get this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function json_encode()
```

I think the extensions are not inherited in subdirectories
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following lines to .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
     suPHP_ConfigPath /home/jciraba1/public_html
</IfModule>
```

this make the php.ini recursive